# How to create cache expiry policy in ignite server by xml?

Tags: java, ignite

This is my example-default.xml,

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="CacheExpiryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
           <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
               <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                      <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                          <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                          <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                      </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
               </bean>
           </property>
        </bean>
        </property>
```

But the above gives Bean property 'CacheExpiryPolicy' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an apache-ignite-users forum question on this.

Please refer to this [here](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/XML-Format-for-Expiry-Policies-td19294.html)

So, the final updated xml according to that forum reference is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Added cache expiry policy -->
    <bean id="cacheExpiryPolicy"
        class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder$SingletonFactory">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                        <constructor-arg value="MINUTES" />
                        <constructor-arg value="5" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg"
        class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default 
            is false. -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events -->
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED" />

                <!--Cache events -->
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- set the cacheConfiguration property -->
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="default" />
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean parent="cacheExpiryPolicy" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: @JAYAPRAKASH It should. You have to check.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example from the [documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-architecture/expiry-policies#configuration):

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cacheWithExpiryPolicy"/>
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                                    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
</property>
```